# Files added to web projects in VS for Mac generate 404 when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I might be going slightly crazy here or simply don't understand how VS on Mac is meant to work. I've used VS on PC for many years but this is my first time on a Mac.

I'm running VS 2022 17.6.3 on macOS Ventura 13.5. I've created a standard ASP.NET Core Web Application using the built in template. As part of the template, Bootstrap and jQuery are included, but I want Bootstrap 5.3 (dark mode ftw). So I've gone into NuGet and added the latest Bootstrap package. The requisite css and js files are copied into /wwwroot/css and /wwwroot/js - at least in Solution Explorer. If you browse to the underlying files in Finder, they're not there. And when running the project, a call to any of the added files results in an HTTP 404.

Files manually added to the same folders in Solution Explorer are created inside the underlying folders.

I understand the path for the NuGet package contents is set to ~/.nuget/packages/. I've tried setting the file properties to copy to the output directory, but it doesn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately using the bootstrap NuGet package means the files are only available in the wwwroot directory if you 'dotnet publish' to a folder. When building or debugging the files are not available to use since they remain in the NuGet package, they are content files so are not local copied during a build. I suspect Visual Studio on Windows has the same bheaviour here. Also when debugging the files have to exist in the project's wwwroot directory, not the bin directory, since that is set as the working directory in VS Mac.